# iOS - Custom Keyboard button like evernote

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, keyboard

I intend to create ' buttons ' to edit the text in a textview like evernote. Such a thing:

[image]

I have no idea how to do :(

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

> NOTE: Do not forget make textView delegate.

```
UIToolbar *keyboardDoneButtonView = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
[keyboardDoneButtonView sizeToFit];

UIBarButtonItem *flexible = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];
UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done"
                                                               style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self
                                                              action:@selector(doneClicked:)];

[keyboardDoneButtonView setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:flexible, doneButton, nil]];


self.textView.inputAccessoryView = keyboardDoneButtonView;
```

IBAction function:

```
- (IBAction)doneClicked:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Done Clicked.");
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```